# nginx版のhttpd -Sは?

Tags: apache, nginx

Apacheでつかえる`httpd -S`コマンドのようなものはnginxではどうやってやるのでしょうか。

設定したドメインを確認したいのですが。

Answer (score 3):

nginxは `httpd -S` とそっくりなコマンドがありません。`nginx -V` はコンパイル・オプションを表示するけど、あるいは `nginx -t` が設定を確認するコマンドです。

[Crossplane](https://github.com/nginxinc/crossplane) というユーティリティはnginxの設定を読み込んで表示することができます。